# How to save/upload image into mongodb using c# asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am trying to create **asp.net mvc** app with users for biliard amateur league (this is my practice project), and store players data into **MongoDb**, but i don't know how to insert picture for player. For now i can put field like **Name**, **Surname** etc. Here's my code for:

Create function:

```
public void Create(Player player)
    {
        playerCollection.InsertOne(player);
    }
```

Create controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Player player)
    {
        playerModel.Create(player);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Player object:

```
public class Player 
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Surname")]
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    //[BsonElement("Picture")]
    //public byte[] Picture{ get; set; } <- I commented on that until I found a solution
}
```

I guess the **HttpPostedFileBase** must be used, but ... I do not know how to implement logic. (and if possible without GridFS).

Cure my headaches! :)

> Edit

---

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Player player, HttpPostedFileBase choosenPicture)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (choosenPicture != null)
            {
                player.Picture = new byte[choosenPicture.ContentLength];

                Stream str = choosenPicture.InputStream;
                str.Read(player.Picture, 0, choosenPicture.ContentLength);
            }
            try
            {
                db.Players.Add(player);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Error :(";
            }
        }

        return View(player);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that storing images in Mongo is such a good idea? Especially with the size of an individual document being limited to [16mb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents)? Not to mention the load that it would put on your database to serve the images. I'd argue that it's better to use some kind of file system based, or cloud-based storage.

Comment: The idea is to save the thumbnails of the players and will have a maximum of 64 players. Therefore, 16mb is enough space for a individual document for these purposes.

Comment: Whats wrong with your approach using the byte array?

Comment: @SJFJ as I said, I can not implement logic. when I try to submit form it returns an error 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters ...' , and to mention that I set up controls in the form just like the input parameters of the function.. see edited.